# Can't login to VPS with newly created account via ssh

Tags: server, ssh, vps

Recently I've bought a VPS Server. I decided to install Ubuntu on it. I want to set up a git server on it but I have problem.

I've read I should create new account for this purpose. I've already done it but I can't login to it via: `ssh git@ip.adres.here`.
It displays an error message: `Permissions denied, please try again`.

Any advice? I'm new to Linux so please try to explain it as easy as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've written it (`ssh git@ip.adres.here`), ssh is trying to login to the host `ip.adres.here` as user `git`. Unless you have a `git` user created on your computer host `ip.adres.here`, you will not be able to login, and will be greeted with "Permissions denied, please try again". (NB: You WILL be asked for a password, even if that username does not exist). If this does not answer your question, please provide more details.

Comment: I've created user git on host computer. I just can't login to it. I can only login as a root. I've read also about sshd_config file and AllowUsers. But there is no line with AllowUsers and I read that if this line doesn't exist all users are able to login.

Comment: I've found also that usePAM was enabled, so i've changed it to 'no'. But it didn't resolve my problems.

Comment: Perhaps post your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, if it does not contain sensitive information. It can be considered sensitive information itself, but unlikely since you're probably running with a default setup. You can print this file by issuing the command `> cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SepHp5cv Here it is.

Comment: Ok, other than the PAM setting, you're using default settings. Are you able to switch users once you're logged in as root? What is the result of the command `su git`?

Comment: It changes the user from root to git.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out. I had bad ip adress. The adress belonged to a machine that is host of OpenVZ not my machine. When i changed ip and forwarded ports everything is just fine. Thanks anyway.